# What causes scrollbar go to 0 when autoscroll changed to false

Tags: c#, autoscroll

I am making a Form that shows charts of signals.
This form has a flowlayout panel with charts as items ordered vertiaclly.
The flowlayout panel is scrollable and the charts inside it are zoomable. Therefore, whenever I try to zoom inside the chart, the event interfere with the scroll event of the flowlayout panel.
Preventing this from happening, I changed autoscroll of the flowlayout panel to false when the mouse enters the chart, and then changed it back to true when the mouse leaves the chart.

However, whenever the autoscroll is changed to false, it also changes its position to 0 returning the scrollbar to the begining.

I need to know where is this function that changes the position of the scrollbar to 0 when autoscroll is changed to false, and how can I prevent it from changing the position of the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.autoscroll?view=netcore-3.1) about the Form.AutoScroll property, setting this property to false should not influence the position. However, the Form.Autoscroll property only makes it possible to make the scrollbar active on controls that are outside of the form panel. For example, a list that gets incrementally generated will influence the position of the scrollbox everytime a new listitem gets added to the list.

There's also no function that sets the position of the scrollbox in the scrollbar. It's the ScrollBar.Value property which influences the position and this property has a default position of 0 (source: [The ScrollBar.Value property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.scrollbar.value?view=netcore-3.1)).